# How to default Grid Splitter collapse status

Tags: silverlight

I want to default close status of grid splitter when my silverlight application starts, how can I do this?

I set IsCollapsed="true", but this doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to make the grid splitter not visible at the startup, set Visibility="Collapsed".

```
<sdk:GridSplitter x:Name="MyGridSplitter" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

This works for me.

If you want to set the grid splitter to visible, you habe to change the visibility to visible e.g. in code behind.

```
MyGridSplitter.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Does this help you?